# how to make mysql check whether there is a space or - in the surname before doing the substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making logins for a school website and I have a list of names, first name + surname.
Now I have this code:

```
UPDATE tblusers t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     UserId,
     CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Surname, 1 ,4), SUBSTRING(Firstname,1,4)) Login
   FROM tblusers
) t2 ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId
SET t1.login = t2.login
```

example: **Johny bravo** will have the loginname **bravjohn**.
But when someone is called "**Van Mullem Arnault**" this becomes **Van Arna**
How do I het rid of that space? or a "-" sign for special names.
So i actually want for "**Van Mullem Arnault**" --> **VanMArna**

I have been looking on the net and here but not really something intesting to find.
Thank you for looking into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MySQL Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE tblusers t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     UserId,
     CONCAT(REPLACE(Surname, ' ' ,''), REPLACE(Firstname, ' ','')) Login
   FROM tblusers
) t2 ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId
SET t1.login = t2.login
```

Comment: This forgets about my substrings :p

Comment: I just took yours and added the substring part myself and it works :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can apply `TRIM` function

```
....CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTRING(Surname, 1 ,4)), TRIM(SUBSTRING(Firstname,1,4)))....
```

or the string is on the *inside* part of the string, use `REPLACE`

```
....CONCAT(REPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(Surname, 1 ,4)), ' ',''), 
           REPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(Firstname,1,4)), ' ', ''))....
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/973dc/1)

Comment: This party solves the issue but this makes vanarna from Van Mullem Arnault in stead of vanmarna.
But I can live with that :p
Thanks a lot!